# Why do we need salt and RFC in generating AES encrypted message

Tags: aes, .net, salt

I'm not very familiar with encryption and new to this, I'm just learning it right now by code review of one of the class we have in an application to encrypt a password using AES. Would anyone explain to me why do we need to have salt and RFC.

Example Snippets: passing parameters compose of input, salt and rfc string.

```
public static string AesEncrypt(string input, string salt, string rfcpassword)
{
  //code here...
}
```

Comment: Do you know what that "rfc" stands for?

Comment: that's the thing I don't know :)

Comment: It would help to see more code, but it's probably the encryption key

Comment: Do not encrypt passwords.  Hash them.  Read this: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm  RFCs are "Requests for Comments," the standards documents of the Internet.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments

Comment: @BobBrown why should I not encrypt passwords?

Comment: Because encryption is reversible and creates an unnecessary security exposure.  (Really... go read the Crackstation article.)

Comment: Could "salt" be the IV named by someone who doesn't know what an IV is?

Comment: @cpast:  That's a better guess than I have.  I really would like to know  where that declaration came from in order to guess whether it might be good for anything.

Comment: @BobBrown there are a few legitimate reasons for encrypting passwords, and a blanket answer of "you never should" is rarely an accurate response.

Comment: @Desthro:  Of course one encrypt could one's *own* passwords for safe storage, as with a password manager program.  I can't think of any reason why someone running a system that requires a password to log in should encrypt rather than hash, and I'd be happy to hear a counter-example.